# MS Outlook 2010 Split Contacts Into Two Groups

Tags: outlook, contacts

I recently upgraded from Outlook 2007 to 2010. In Contacts, the Contacts are now split into two "groups" - they weren't in 2007.

I haven't been able to figure out why they're split, or find any suggestions via Googling, so any suggestions would be very welcome![image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to customize the current view in Outlook. See [the video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yq5x3SdR3jU).

Also you may implement the required task using VBA programmatically. The [CurrentView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff864212(v=office.15).aspx) property of the Folder or Explorer classes returns a View object representing the current view.

To obtain a View object for the view of the current Explorer, use Explorer.CurrentView instead of the CurrentView property of the current Folder object returned by Explorer.CurrentFolder.

Views are defined and customized using the View object's [XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868419.aspx) property. The XML property allows you to create and set a customized XML schema that defines the various features of a view.

Comment: Thanks Eugene, tutorial was helpful. Found the problem:  View tab > View Settings > Group By. I set it to "(none)", which fixed my problem.